# how to use a while loop in a while loop

Tags: python, error-handling

How do I make it so that I can have a while loop in my while loop if someone does not input either 'y' or 'n'? Can someone put it into my code?

```
redo = False

outstanding = 0
satisfactory = 0
unsatisfactory = 0
mark_Total = 0
value = False
while not redo:
    try:
        mark = input("Enter a mark from 0-100")
        if mark < 0 or mark >= 100:
            raise ValueError("Invalid Input")
        elif mark >= 90:
            outstanding += 1
            mark_Total += 1
            again = raw_input("Do you want to enter another mark? (y/n)")
            if again.lower() == "n":
                redo = True
```

Answer (score 2):

Where's nothing special about using a `while` loop inside another loop.

```
    elif mark >= 90:
        outstanding += 1
        mark_Total += 1
        again = 'x'
        while again != 'y' and again != 'n':
            again = raw_input("Do you want to enter another mark? (y/n)").lower()
        if again == "y":
            redo = True
```